# API Error using a Sandbox account

Tags: javascript, java, html, square, square-connect

I am trying to test out the Web API using the example code from the [documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/web-api-ios). My code lauches the app but throws an error in the app:

*API Error
Sorry, we could not process the incoming request. Please try again or contact support.*

My url that I'm send after it's encoded is as follws:

```
square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data=%7B%22amount_money%22%3A%7B%22amount%22%3A%22500%22%2C%22currency_code%22%3A%22USD%22%7D%2C%22callback_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fjaydien.ezservicetrax.com%2F%22%2C%22client_id%22%3A%22sandbox-sq0idp-CHLAPYt9s1L594ZZZysDSQ%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.3%22%2C%22notes%22%3A%22notes%20for%20the%20transaction%22%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22supported_tender_types%22%3A%5B%22CREDIT_CARD%22%2C%22CASH%22%2C%22OTHER%22%2C%22SQUARE_GIFT_CARD%22%2C%22CARD_ON_FILE%22%5D%7D%7D
```

Here is my code:

```
    <script>
  var dataParameter = {
    "amount_money": {
      "amount" : "500",
      "currency_code" : "USD"
    },
    "callback_url" : "https://jaydien.ezservicetrax.com/", // Replace this value with your application's callback URL
    "client_id" : "sandbox-sq0idp-CHLAPYt9s1L594ZZZysDSQ", // Replace this value with your application's ID
    "version": "1.3",
    "notes": "notes for the transaction",
    "options" : {
      "supported_tender_types" : ["CREDIT_CARD","CASH","OTHER","SQUARE_GIFT_CARD","CARD_ON_FILE"]
    }
  };
  window.location = "square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(dataParameter));
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are attempting to use your sandbox application/client id. At this time, we don't support a sandbox for the Point of Sale APIs, but you can use cash transactions to get the same effect. That error message could be improved though, so I'll bring this up with the team.

To fix your error, replace your sandbox client/application id with your actual: `sq0idp-CHLAPYt9s1L594ZZZysDSQ`

Comment: Thank you. I noticed after some trial and error that my regular ID would work so I've been testing with that. Great idea about the cash, that will help with the testing. I've been struggling for a couple hours now with an issue about the dollar amount. The $500 in my example is being processed as 5.00 in the APP, 50,000 will translate to 500? Any idea on why that would be

Comment: Yep, In the documentation, currencies and amounts are listed as being the smallest base unit. For USD that is cents, For JPN that is yen. So all your prices will be charged in cents.

Comment: So I need to add two zeros to each dollar amount number?

Comment: Not exactly, a better way to think about it would be to multiply you values by 100, since there are 100 cents in a dollar. So $5 would be 500 and $2,59 would be 259.